# Can anyone trace this program to help me better grasp how recursion works

Tags: c++, recursion

The program solves the Tower of Hanoi puzzle. The objective of the puzzle is to move an entire stack of disks to another rod, obeying the following simple rules:

Only one disk can be moved at a time.
Each move consists of taking the upper disk from one of the stacks and placing it on top of another stack or on an empty rod.
No larger disk may be placed on top of a smaller disk.
With 3 disks, the puzzle can be solved in 7 moves. The minimal number of moves required to solve a Tower of Hanoi puzzle is 2^n − 1, where n is the number of disks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void tower(int n, char start, char end, char help)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    tower(n - 1, start, help, end);
    printf("\nDisk %d has been moved from tower %c to tower %c", n, start, 
    end);
    tower(n - 1, help, end, start);
}

int main()
{
    tower(3, 'A', 'C', 'B');
    return 0;
}`
```

Comment: Q: Can anybody help me trace this program...  A: Sure.  What debugger do you have handy? GDB?  Visual Studio IDE?  Other?  Just start in "debug" mode, single step through the code, and inspect the variables as you go.  Learning your debugger ... is EVERY bit as important as learning your compiler.  IMHO...

Comment: In Visual Studio Single step is pressing `F11` to execute a line or step into a function. Press `F10` to skip over some function you don't want to step into. You can also set breakpoints with `F9` and then press `F5` to run till it hits your breakpoint. When the code stops at a line look at the variables of interest. Other debuggers have similar options which may be associated with  the same or different keys.

Answer (score 2):

In many environments running through a debugger just in not available.  In particular embedded systems, or jobs that are running for *N* days on production before an error happens.

In these scenarios, logging the flow of the program with a simple `printf()` or a more sophisticated logging function can be one of the only ways to work out what happened.

Similarly with tracing the recursive flow of execution, simply add a print to your function:

```
void tower(int n, char start, char end, char help)
{
    printf("tower(n=%d, start=%c, end=%c, help=%c)\n", n, start, end, help);
    ...
```

Giving:

```
tower(n=3, start=A, end=C, help=B)
tower(n=2, start=A, end=B, help=C)
tower(n=1, start=A, end=C, help=B)
tower(n=0, start=A, end=B, help=C)
Disk 1 has been moved from tower A to tower C
tower(n=0, start=B, end=C, help=A)
Disk 2 has been moved from tower A to tower B
tower(n=1, start=C, end=B, help=A)
tower(n=0, start=C, end=A, help=B)
Disk 1 has been moved from tower C to tower B
tower(n=0, start=A, end=B, help=C)
Disk 3 has been moved from tower A to tower C
tower(n=2, start=B, end=C, help=A)
tower(n=1, start=B, end=A, help=C)
tower(n=0, start=B, end=C, help=A)
Disk 1 has been moved from tower B to tower A
tower(n=0, start=C, end=A, help=B)
Disk 2 has been moved from tower B to tower C
tower(n=1, start=A, end=C, help=B)
tower(n=0, start=A, end=B, help=C)
Disk 1 has been moved from tower A to tower C
tower(n=0, start=B, end=C, help=A)
```

There are also the handy compiler macros `__FILE__`, `__FUNCTION__` and `__LINE__` (and a couple more, depends on your compiler).  Which can be embedded into log/print statements:

```
printf( "Something eldritch happened in %s at %s:%d\n", __FUNCTION__, __FILE__, __LINE__ );
```